# Rotate a camera on its centre

Tags: camera, three.js

What I want to do is to rotate a camera on it's centre while the camera position is steady. So as a result when the user clicks and moves the mouse he will get all the perspectives possible from that point of view.

I am using trackback controls so I have tried things like:

```
controls.target.set(camera.position.x,camera.position.y,camera.position.z);
```

but it does not give the wanted result. I am looking something like camera rotation on axes x,y,z while the camera position is the same.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to keep `TrackballControls`, set a very close `target` (set the camera position and the `controls.target` to very close coordinates, but different ones).
- Otherwise use [`PointerLockControls`](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_pointerlock)